# change levels of column names of a matrix for plotting heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, levels, pheatmap

I have my matrix and I'm ready to plot a heatmap using the `pheatmap` package in R.

My matrix is like:

```
Name A B C
Apple 1 2 3
Banana 4 5 6
Pear 7 8 9
```

If I don't cluster the column, the heatmap will order the columns as A, B and C. What if I want to set the order as B, C, A?

I tried:

```
colnames(matrix)<-factor(colnames(matrix),levels = c("B","C","A"))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-order the columns of your matrix manually.

```
mat <- as.matrix(data.frame(df[, -1], row.names = df[, 1]))

library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(mat[, c("B", "C", "A")], cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F)
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Name A B C
Apple 1 2 3
Banana 4 5 6
Pear 7 8 9", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But can I set the level for column names outside the pheatmap? As I would like to apply the level to other plots as well

Comment: @LennonLee I'm not really sure what you mean. You can just reorder the columns prior to plotting, e.g. `mat <- mat[, c("B", "C", "A")]`.